# 'Invoke-Expression' dropping double quote

Tags: powershell

I have a directory structure with ZIP files in it, and I'd like to extract them with a script.

My script so far:

```
$7zexe = "c:\bin\7za.exe"
$arg = ""
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.zip |
ForEach-Object { $argout = $_.Directory.Name
  $arg = " e `"$_`" -o`"$argout`""
  $cmdline = $7zexe, $arg -join ""
  $cmdline
  Invoke-Expression -command  "$cmdline "
}
```

But I get the following error

```
c:\bin\7za.exe e "E:\tmp\the folder\the sub folder\my_big_file.zip" -o"the sub folder"
Invoke-Expression : The string starting:
At line:1 char:86
 + c:\bin\7za.exe e "E:\tmp\the folder\the sub folder\my_big_file.zip" -o"the sub folder <<<< "
 is missing the terminator: ".
At x:\mydocs\testscript.ps1:9 char:18
+ Invoke-Expression <<<<  -command  "$cmdline "
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ( :String) [Invoke-Expression], IncompleteParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Somehow it looks like PowerShell is dropping my closing `"`.

I tried it with the `&` operator and I also tried to replace the arguments with an array:

```
[Array]$arg = "e ", "`"$_`""," -o`"$argout`""
```

Comment: See also *[Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put the -o inside the quotes:

```
$7zexe = "c:\bin\7za.exe"
$arg = ""
Get-ChildItem -recurse -Include *.zip | 
ForEach-Object { $argout = $_.Directory.FullName
  write-host -ForegroundColor Green $argout
  $arg = " e `"$_`" `"-o$argout`""
  $cmdline = $7zexe, $arg -join ""
  $cmdline
  Invoke-Expression -command  "$cmdline "
}
```

**Sidenote:** To make sure the contents of a deeply nested zip file gets unzipped to the correct directory I believe you should use the fullname property of the containing directory.

Comment: Thanks
It looks like the solution but I still had some problems cleaning up the enviroment (somehow the powershell was convinced &arg is an array???!?
adding 
    `[string]$arg = ""`
solved this problem to