# powershell invoke-expression issue

Tags: powershell

I have a command to extract a file using 7z and it works in a DOS command line. The command is:

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\7z.exe" x -o"C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\utils" "C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\rsasecureidtoken411.zip"
```

Now I have to run the upper command in powershell, I use a `call operator` & to call it (in Powershell command line), but it seems there are some errors with it. It just shows *>>* at the next line when I press enter, and I have to press Ctrl + c to stop the command.

```
PS C:\> & "C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\7z.exe" x -o"C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\utils" "C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\RSASecurIDToken411.zip"
>>
>>
>>
>>
>>
>>
PS C:\>
```

I've also tried `invoke-expression` but still can't make it work. Anyone can help with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
[string]$pathToZipExe = "C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\7z.exe"
[Array]$arguments = "x", "-oC:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\utils", "C:\Documents and Settings\e.DEV\My Documents\RSASecurIDToken411.zip"

& $pathToZipExe $arguments
```

Comment: Thanks C.B! I just found another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128276/invoke-expression-dropping-double-quote which is related to my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Yousui Glad to help! Separing command and arguments in this way is more easy to manage in eventually foraech loop in scripts.